# fetch JSON from google spreadsheet using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-sheets-api

I want to fetch JSON from google spreadsheet, I searched few links but cannot find the exact solution.

Can someone help me with the solution.

https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/json 
http://www.mail-archive.com/google-help-dataapi@googlegroups.com/msg01924.html 
http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/js.html 
http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/gadgets/
http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0developers_guide_protocol.html#UploadingDocs

Regards 
Anup Singh

Comment: What *specifically* are you unsure about? And you'll need to accept some more answers to previous questions if you want people to continue to help you.

Answer (score 2):

A little late but here's the workflow:

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238935/google-spreadsheets-api-with-oauth2-0-using-javascript) for proper OAuth authorization if your spreadsheet is private.

Your spreadsheet key can be found by going to Google Drive and looking at your spreadsheet.  In the url is the string "key=xxxx".  The 'xxxx' is your Spreadsheet key.

Then merely do the following:

```
var token = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
var urlLocation = ''; //put the spreadsheet key here
var url = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/' + urlLocation + '/od6/private/full?alt=json-in-script&access_token=' + token + '&callback=?';

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it finished the start of the solution I found in the Google Docs where you had to get the gapi token set up with the rights scopes (https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds) etc. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample

here is an example.

Note this JSON only works for ["published"](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#spreadsheets_api_urls_visibilities_and_projections) spreadsheets.