# Importing JSON via Google Spreadsheet API

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-sheets-api, google-oauth

I just want to pull my spreadsheet into an app/website.  Ideally, I'd like it to be private, but first I'm trying to bring in the data with the spreadsheet "available to the public" and "published to the web".

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: 'http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/' + spreadsheetKey + '/od6/public/full?alt=json',
   success: function(data){
     alert("success");
   } 
 });
```

This always results in:

"You do not have view access to the spreadsheet. Make sure you are properly authenticated."

I've tried without ?alt=json, with 'list' instead of 'cells', and with 'values' instead of 'full'.  Nothing works.

Also, is there a way to pass the access token into this call?  I'm authenticating via Google Sign-In and allowing for Spreadsheet API scope.  I've tried &accessToken=xxx and &access_token=xxx.  The documentation doesn't have anything for Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

For Javascript access to a private spreadsheet, you'll need the Javascript library here: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/wiki/Authentication  That allows you to use OAuth2.0 which allows you to access a private Google Spreadsheet.  See the answer under [Google Spreadsheets API with OAuth 2.0 using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238935/google-spreadsheets-api-with-oauth2-0-using-javascript) for a full description.

For the access token, the syntax is:
`&access_token=xxx`  The relevant details for Javascript is under the Protocol heading in the [Google Spreadsheet API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/), but it isn't that helpful I've found.

To get JSON do the following:

```
var url = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/' + urlLocation + '/od6/private/full?alt=json-in-script&access_token=' + token + '&callback=?';
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    //do stuff with data here
});
```