# Google Private Spreadsheet Javascript Oauth

Tags: oauth, google-sheets-api

I have been trying to fully understand the Google APIs so I can grab data from a Google spreadsheet that is private using Javascript.

I am using jQuery and D3.js to create a chart and I want to seamlessly pull the data without the user being redirected to an authorization page. I know I need to use OAuth, but I can't find any examples of how to do this seamlessly through an AJAX call.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#authorizing_requests
This doesn't mention anything that makes it seem like I can do it without an OAuth dialog to the user.

Comment: please explain "without an OAuth dialog". My understanding is, OAuth requires such a page. What kind of authorization do you want to use?  OR ... to do it with a password, you can use this outdated (not very secure) method: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/sample/spreadsheet/cell/CellDemo.java?r=51 But I think you need to use OAuth with AJAX

Comment: I was looking for a way to use a spreadsheet basically as a database. So, the user could just go to the page and the data would automatically be loaded and processed by javascript. I think you're right that I can't get around the OAuth authentication dialog page.

Comment: google-apps-script offers a mix of server and client side java script for google docs spreadsheet etc.

Answer (score 0):

To get a private spreadsheet page, you're going to have to authorize.  See [Google Spreadsheets API with OAuth 2.0 for Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238935/google-spreadsheets-api-with-oauth2-0-using-javascript/14314557#14314557) for a complete working OAuth call for a Google Spreadsheet.  I used this to create a working database using Google Spreadsheets.

Another way that might work: [Fusion Tables](http://www.google.com/drive/apps.html#fusiontables).  You will have to have a public sheet, but you can make it unlisted meaning it is only available through a link (which you only use in your javascript).  It might want a location (as it was designed for spatial data), but you might be able to get around it or just use a dummy value.