# Google spreadsheet api Request had insufficient authentication scopes

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-sheets-api

I'm making an script to read data from google spreadsheet using the following script on nodejs:

```
var url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type:     'offline',
    approval_prompt: 'force',
    scope: [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
    ]
});
global.googleapis = { expiry_date: 0 };
google.options({ auth: oauth2Client });
var sheets    = google.sheets('v4');
sheets.spreadsheets.get({ spreadsheetId: 'id'}, function(err, data) {
    res.send(err, data);
});
```

But on every get request i'm getting this error:

```
Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
```

I checked the Google developers console to enable the Google Drive API and it's enabled, so I dont really know what could it be.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

1. Firstly delete the credentials files `~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-nodejs-quickstart.json` (depending on your setting)
2. Change the scope variable used for reading cells from Google Spreadsheets from

> var SCOPES =
>   ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'];

to

> var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'];

3. After the execution of code, API will authenticate again and then the issue will be resolved.

Comment: This answers the question in the most straightforward fashion (and explains why the error occurs in the first place)!

Comment: You don't have to delete the credentials.json, only remove token.js and change scope in nodejs project. Then you need to do that link authentication again.

Comment: Deleting the json file does nothing. I had to delete the token.json directory NOT the json credential file. Now it actually works.

Comment: This relieved a massive and growing headache. Thanks, Long and J-Ho!

Comment: there is no credentials file on my drive - my code is executing on the Google server because it is written in Google Apps Script - the advanced Classroom API is on. No spreadsheet involved although script is bound to spreadsheet. This information is meaningless to me.

Comment: @aNewb You are welcome to contribute the answer for the case executed on the Google server. Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

The scopes look good, maybe you should try to remove the credentials stored previously in `/Users/yourUserName/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-projectName/*`, and then execute the application again to get new credentials.

Answer (score 8):

First, make sure you also **enable the Sheets API** in your Developers Console.

The `insufficient authentication scopes` is an error in the OAuth 2.0 token provided in the request specifies [scopes](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/authorizing#OAuth2Authorizing) that are insufficient for accessing the requested data.

So make sure you use the correct and all necessary scope and check this [Authorizing requests with OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/authorizing#AboutAuthorization) if you properly follow the steps here.

Lastly, try to revoke the access and try to redo it.

For more information, check this related SO question:

- [Write to GoogleSheet via API with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37520782/write-to-googlesheet-via-api-with-java)
- [Google Spreadsheets API with OAuth2.0 using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238935/google-spreadsheets-api-with-oauth2-0-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

In my case a token.pickle file was created in the same working directory as my program, I also had my credentials.json file in the same directory, all I did was deleted the token.pickle file , then changed the scope, then ran it again, it will again ask for authentication in your browser and that's it , it works.

My code snippet is like below , I was creating a pickle file so I had to delete it before changing scope

```
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server()
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete the token from tokens folder and try again. If you have tried to run the Google Drive Quickstart before running the Spreadsheet Quickstart, the existing token might not have the spreadsheet access updated.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem occurred when I updated the scope. Along with the instruction, I delete the token.json file under the same directory with the python script, then the Authentication scope issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the credential location for long time.  Lot of forum mentioned that it'd be under c:\users\.credentials\google-api****.json  But I couldn't find them anywhere.  Then I figured out that my program created a *token.pickle* file right in the *program .py* directory which is essentially the credential file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Java + IntellijIdea) I deleted a file: `~/IdeaProjects/projectName/tokens/StoredCredential` and restarted code.

This folder was created with `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder`, so may be different, but the file should be the same.

After restarting I have switched to the Quickstart page again for access managing - give all access for the user and follow.

After that, all work well for me

Answer (score -1):

Also please check the installed version of googleapis in your workspace, because the latest version (51) does not support for Node 8. So you need downgrade its version.
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/releases

Answer (score -1):

as @herrogokunaruto mentioned, ensure token.pickle file is not present in the workspacefolder

Answer (score -1):

Select proper permission granting access to google sheets read, edit, etc, when OAuth popup open for asking google account permissions

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score -1):

Using a newer version of the google sheets npm module I had to delete the local file "token.json" to re-trigger the auth and it worked.

Also, make sure you change your "scopes" to have auth permissions instead of read-only.