# Insufficient Permission trying to access Google Sheets API

Tags: google-sheets

I have created a project in the Google Developer Console. I have enabled the Google Sheets API in the project and created a Service Account. I granted the Service Account a handful of IAM permissions (Project Owner, App Engine Admin, Cloud Mail Admin, and Storage Admin).

But when I try to use this Service Account to create a Sheet, I get a 403 `Insufficient Permission`.

What do I need to do to allow this Service Account to create and work with a Google Sheet?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code. There is no visible effort shown here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534801/google-spreadsheet-api-request-had-insufficient-authentication-scopes)

Answer (score 0):

Gspread doesn't work if you have two-factor authorization turned on for your account.