# Accessing Google Sheets Api with Python

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I'm currently trying to make updates to google sheets via python and I'm running into some issues with permissions.

I've been following the instructions from this Twilio guide:https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/02/an-easy-way-to-read-and-write-to-a-google-spreadsheet-in-python.html

I'm doing all of this in Jupyter, and I did save the JSON file to the proper code directory. I had no problems defining scope, creds and client.

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_id.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open("MixIQ Tracker").sheet1
```

I've followed all of the steps to link the two, but I am getting this API Error with the last line.

```
APIError: {
"error": {
  "errors": [{
      "domain": "global",
      "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
      "message": "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."
    }],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."
 }
}
```

I'm not exactly sure how to resolve this. Any direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534801/google-spreadsheet-api-request-had-insufficient-authentication-scopes

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I believe google drive API endpoint needs to be included in your scope. I was writing data from Mailchimp API to Google Sheet.

Check this out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7I2s81TsCnc> It was helpful for me.

```
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
```

Comment: Updating that scope and enabling google sheet API helped me

Comment: Updating scope with the second term helped me fix this as well

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [google API scopes documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes), the scope url you are using is not referenced anywhere. This may be the problem. Try changing the scope url to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`.

Also, make sure the spreadsheet API is correctly enabled in your project in the google developer console.

Alternatively, you could try the [Sheetfu library](https://github.com/socialpoint-labs/sheetfu) (I'm the author), that handles the scopes for you.

Answer (score 2):

Use this as your scope:

```
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
```

Before calling the "ServiceAccountCredentials"

You will need to enable the Google Drive API in the "console.cloud.google" as well as the sheets API.

Answer (score 0):

You only need this scope

```
scope = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
```