# How do I resolve a 403 for accessing Sheets API via Python

Tags: python, google-apps-script, pickle, google-sheets-api, google-workspace

I am trying to build a script on my local machine using Python that will download a Google sheet from my account using a short lived federated identity token. I have seen documentation that speaks about differences between doing this depends on context, so starting on a MacOS running Monterey and VScode, and later to HA (Minikube, k9s, etc. and then cloud).

I have enabled the Sheets API via the browser for the current project, obtained a client ID and secret, and have the cli installed. I ran a `gcloud auth application-default login`. I am currently seeing a 403 and potentially insufficient scopes. Older posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56084171/accessing-google-sheets-api-with-python) speaks of clobbering/modifying the .credentials and starting with a proper scope. I know a lot has changed with variable length tokens, scope and all since 2019...

Also I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534801/google-spreadsheet-api-request-had-insufficient-authentication-scopes) on recommendation from Workspaces support, and seem to be in a pickle, pardon the pun;) Is it still a pickle I'm going to deal with here?

Here is my current code:

```py
"""
BEFORE RUNNING:
---------------
1. If not already done, enable the Google Sheets API
   and check the quota for your project at
   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sheets
2. Install the Python client library for Google APIs by running
   `pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client`
"""
from pprint import pprint

from googleapiclient import discovery

# TODO: Change placeholder below to generate authentication credentials. See
# https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample
#
# Authorize using one of the following scopes:
#     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
#     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
#     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'
#     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
#     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'
credentials = None

service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

# The ID of the spreadsheet to retrieve data from.
spreadsheet_id = ''  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

# The A1 notation of the values to retrieve.
range_ = 'A1:Y1'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

# How values should be represented in the output.
# The default render option is ValueRenderOption.FORMATTED_VALUE.
value_render_option = ''  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

# How dates, times, and durations should be represented in the output.
# This is ignored if value_render_option is
# FORMATTED_VALUE.
# The default dateTime render option is [DateTimeRenderOption.SERIAL_NUMBER].
date_time_render_option = ''  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

# request = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_, valueRenderOption=value_render_option, dateTimeRenderOption=date_time_render_option)
# response = request.execute()

# errors here from above

request = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_)
response = request.execute()

# TODO: Change code below to process the `response` dict:
pprint(response)
```

and the latest error:

```
raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1234567long_spreadsheet_id/values/A1%3AY1?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo', 'reason': 'ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT', 'domain': 'googleapis.com', 'metadata': {'service': 'sheets.googleapis.com', 'method': 'google.apps.sheets.v4.SpreadsheetsService.GetValues'}}]"
```

If someone could point me in a good direction- either detailed current documentation as it relates to python (I may have to back up and punt with Apps Script or something for the time being and POC), or nudge me with some pseudocode in the way I need to properly authenticate to get my credential file working with a short lived token (IMHO better for the time being than having a small business trying to manage keys on GCP) and possibly for a refresh after it's stale, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I omitted my sheet id on purpose. Any sheet from my drive reports the same issue.

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of the scopes you used in your code? The ones that are currently in the code snippet are commented on, not the actual scopes used scopes. Also, I cannot see the authentication flow. You can see an example in this Google Documentation. You should have something like `SCOPES = ['googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 'googleapis.com/auth/drive', ..... ]

Comment: I may have not added scopes in. In my notes I had the last one listed. It has been only a few days ago, but I've moved forward addressing other concerns. Do you know a specific link or links to documentation that clearly address what is required and optional, and how to "reset" any .credentials that may be improperly configured during the dev process?

Comment: You can re view [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python).