# Insufficient authentication scopes error using Google Slides API

Tags: python, google-slides-api

I'm trying to understand how to work with Google Slides API,

I did everything as it was described [here](https://developers.google.com/slides/quickstart/python).

In "enable Google Slides API" I tried to choose "Desktop app" or "Web Server", but in both ways every time when I try to run `quickstart.py` file, I get same error:

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://slides.googleapis.com/v1/presentations/1EAYk18WDjIG-zp_0vLm3CsfQh_i8eXc67Jo2O9C6Vuc?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">

This is what i have inside my `quickstart.py`:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations.readonly']

# The ID of a sample presentation.
PRESENTATION_ID = '1EAYk18WDjIG-zp_0vLm3CsfQh_i8eXc67Jo2O9C6Vuc'

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Slides API.
    Prints the number of slides and elments in a sample presentation.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('slides', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Slides API
    presentation = service.presentations().get(
        presentationId=PRESENTATION_ID).execute()
    slides = presentation.get('slides')

    print('The presentation contains {} slides:'.format(len(slides)))
    for i, slide in enumerate(slides):
        print('- Slide #{} contains {} elements.'.format(
            i + 1, len(slide.get('pageElements'))))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

*Updated:*

Whole error msg looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/A/PycharmProjects/PyProjects/quickstart.py", line 54, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/A/PycharmProjects/PyProjects/quickstart.py", line 44, in main
    presentationId=PRESENTATION_ID).execute()
  File "/Users/A/PycharmProjects/PyProjects/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/A/PycharmProjects/PyProjects/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 907, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://slides.googleapis.com/v1/presentations/1EAYk18WDjIG-zp_0vLm3CsfQh_i8eXc67Jo2O9C6Vuc?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google spreadsheet api Request had insufficient authentication scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534801/google-spreadsheet-api-request-had-insufficient-authentication-scopes)

Comment: thanks for reply, but nope, this didn't answer my question :(

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution, for example, when `token.pickle` is deleted and reauthorize the scope and run the script again, what result will you get?

Comment: Its says:
# The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.#

if my understanding is correct, token.pickle will be created after authorization flow completes. But it didn't, so i didn't even have this file yet.

Comment: What line number is shown when that error is reported? I just followed the quickstart example and it's working for me. Curious as to why it fails for you..

Comment: @D. Foley please check the update of the post.

Comment: Can you please log into the developer console and double check that the slides API is enabled? I don't think there is anything wrong with the code per se, I think there is a misconfiguration on your account.

Comment: Are you using the `credentials.json` provided by the *quickstart* page or one from a GCP project?

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have stumbled upon the same issue it is easily solvable, you just have to approve it manually.

https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/python#step_1_turn_on_the

So press the Enable the People API button and it should open a new window where you have to login manually first time for the approval hope it helps.