# How to set the scope using Google Operators in Airflow

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I have a task using the [GCSToGoogleSheetsOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/suite/transfers/gcs_to_sheets/index.html) in Airflow where Im trying to add data to a sheet.

I have added the service credential email to the sheet I want to edit with editor privileges, and received this error:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: 
<HttpError 403 when requesting 
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/<SHEET_ID>/values/Sheet1?valueInputOption=RAW&includeValuesInResponse=false&responseValueRenderOption=FORMATTED_VALUE&responseDateTimeRenderOption=SERIAL_NUMBER&alt=json 

returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". 

    Details: "[{
'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo', 
'reason': 'ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT', 
'domain': 'googleapis.com', 
'metadata': {
    'service': 'sheets.googleapis.com', 
    'method': 'google.apps.sheets.v4.SpreadsheetsService.UpdateValues'}
    }]>
```

I cant update the sheet, but the GCS and BigQuery operators work fine.

My connection configuration looks like the following:

```
AIRFLOW_CONN_GOOGLE_CLOUD=google-cloud-platform://?extra__google_cloud_platform__key_path=%2Fopt%2Fairflow%2Fcredentials%2Fgoogle_credential.json
```

I tried following the [instructions](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/connections/gcp.html) to add the [scope](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#sheets) `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`.

Which URL encoded looks like:

```
AIRFLOW_CONN_GOOGLE_CLOUD=google-cloud-platform://?extra__google_cloud_platform__key_path=%2Fopt%2Fairflow%2Fcredentials%2Fgoogle_credential.json&extra__google_cloud_platform__scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fspreadsheets
```

Now, operators which previously worked error out like this:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/my-project/jobs?prettyPrint=false: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
```

And the GCSToGoogleSheetsOperator operator still error out like this:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 GET https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/my-bucket/o/folder%2Fobject.csv?alt=media: Insufficient Permission: ('Request failed with status code', 403, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>, <HTTPStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT: 206>)
```

How can I set the permissions correctly to use both BigQuery, GCS and Sheets operators?

Comment: This error message is about the scope of your request. Can you share with us the list of scope/s that you are using for this request?

Comment: You can refer to this other post with a similar error message as a reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534801/google-spreadsheet-api-request-had-insufficient-authentication-scopes

Comment: Thanks @patrickdc. I tried setting the scope, but got more errors instead, and edited the question. I think Im setting it incorrectly somehow, do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a scope seems to ignore the IAM roles, so its either one or the other.

The service account had roles needed to access GCS and BigQuery, but by adding the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`, the service would ignore the privileges granted by the roles and look only at the ones specified by the scopes.

So, to recover it, you must add both the `spreadsheet` and `cloud-platform` scopes (or more strict scopes). `cloud-platform` will provide access to GCS and BigQuery and `spreadsheets` to Google Sheets API.

If you set your connection using environment variables, you have to URL encode the arguments, so to create a GOOGLE_CLOUD connection, you will have to do something like this, which is not encoded...

```
AIRFLOW_CONN_GOOGLE_CLOUD=google-cloud-platform://?extra__google_cloud_platform__key_path=/abs/path_to_file/credential.json&extra__google_cloud_platform__scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
```

To encode, which is the version you have to use, replace `/`, `,` and `:`:

```
AIRFLOW_CONN_GOOGLE_CLOUD=google-cloud-platform://?extra__google_cloud_platform__key_path=%2Fabs%2Fpath_to_file%2Fcredentials%2Fgoshare-driver-c08e0904285b.json&extra__google_cloud_platform__scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fspreadsheets
```