# google sheet API Request had insufficient authentication scopes

Tags: python, ubuntu, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to follow the Google Sheet API from its documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values

I'm trying to run the snippets of the codes mentioned there, for example, Python code on [Reading a single range](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#reading_a_single_range)

Here is an example of a snippet of code that I ran, `sheets_get_values.py`

```
from __future__ import print_function

import google.auth
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError


def get_values(spreadsheet_id, range_name):
    creds, _ = google.auth.default()
    try:
        service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

        result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
            spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_name).execute()
        rows = result.get('values', [])
        print(f"{len(rows)} rows retrieved")
        return result
    except HttpError as error:
        print(f"An error occurred: {error}")
        return error


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_values("1CM29gwKIzeXsAppeNwrc8lbYaVMmUclprLuLYuHog4k", "A1:C2")
```

`python3 sheets_get_values.py`

But I got this message:

```
An error occurred: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1CM29gwKIzeXsAppeNwrc8lbYaVMmUclprLuLYuHog4k/values/A1%3AC2?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo', 'reason': 'ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT', 'domain': 'googleapis.com', 'metadata': {'method': 'google.apps.sheets.v4.SpreadsheetsService.GetValues', 'service': 'sheets.googleapis.com'}}]">
```

I have tried to set the **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS** environment:

`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='/home/myUser/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json'`

I also already enable application default credentials:

`gcloud auth application-default login`

`gcloud config set project project_name`

I also try to solve this by following a few instructions related to **Request had insufficient authentication scopes** by Googling, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46686130/8070090)

I try to modify the default snippet of code by Google documentation be like this:

```
SCOPES = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
]

def append_values(spreadsheet_id, range_name, value_input_option,
                  _values):
    creds, _ = google.auth.default(scopes=SCOPES)
    ...
    ...
```

But the error still appear when I ran the snippet of the code.

So, what should I do to solve this error?

Comment: do you use v2 auth? 403 means forbiden access.... you shoul dbe getting a token request, then validate etc. just making sure it is not the issue. google is full of old tutorials and had similar issue before...

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

Try [passing in additional scopes](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login#--scopes):

```
gcloud auth application-default login --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
```

You may also need to unset `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` before `application-default login` works.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the Sheet you are trying to get data from. It is unavailable, you can try to [navigate to it](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CM29gwKIzeXsAppeNwrc8lbYaVMmUclprLuLYuHog4k).

Replace the sheet id (`1CM29gwKIzeXsAppeNwrc8lbYaVMmUclprLuLYuHog4k`) with some that is available to your Google account. You can try this one - `1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms` (this is the [test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms)).

Comment: Actually I already tried the real sheet id like this `17rkVniBQLZOrOy6uH-BloWK6nXqfd7IWap64dCu07N8`, but still getting the same error.

Comment: But the sheet [`17rkVniBQLZOrOy6uH-BloWK6nXqfd7IWap64dCu07N8`](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17rkVniBQLZOrOy6uH-BloWK6nXqfd7IWap64dCu07N8) isn't available either, at least for me. Is it your sheet? Perhaps you created it in one account and tried reading from another one that doesn't have access rights.

Comment: HI @elebur, yes, that is my sheet, and I have access to it. And in the other hand actually I also already tried your mentioned id `1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms`, but the result is still the same.

Comment: Hello, @Tri. I am not sure what the problem is, but I assume it is related to the created Google project.
Did you enable Sheet and Drive API? How did you get the credentials?

Comment: Hi @elebur, yes I have enabled the Sheet and Drive API. I created credentials from the **APIs & Services** menu, then on the **Credentials** tab, click on the **CREATE CREDENTIALS** button, then click on the **OAuth client ID**, and on the **Application type** I selected the **Desktop app**, then I download its JSON file, then set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to the JSON file path.

Did I do the wrong step?

Comment: Seems everything is ok with credentials, as for me. Try this code https://pastebin.com/8DGzs7d4, it differs a little from yours.

Comment: When I run the code, it open my browser and require me to authenticate first, after that I got this message on the browser: `The authentication flow has completed. You may close this window.`

But I got this error on my console where I ran the python file:
https://pastebin.com/jWM6XZYV

Comment: @Tri, I've been thinking about your problem but don't know what else it might be.
I still assume it is related to the google project. Try creating a new one (perhaps with a new account).
What is the [publishing status](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent) of the project? Is it "Testing" or "In production"? If it is "testing" try setting "In production".